# What do input() and unput() mean?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have the problem to understand the following snippet code from reading this 'parsing SQL' using flex and bison - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/flex-bison/9780596805418/ch04.html. I am new to flex and bison tool, do not understand how this code is related to COUNT() function in sql. What does input() and unput() do in here ?  Also another function in the same page SUBSTR(ING)?/"(" {return FSUBSTRING}, what does ING mean ?  Does the whole thing mean it matches zero or one of SUBSTR(ING) and follow by ( or "(", which one ?

```
/* check trailing context manually */
COUNT    { int c = input(); unput(c);
       if(c == '(') return FCOUNT;
       yylval.strval = strdup(yytext);
       return NAME; }
```

Comment: http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/tools/Lex_io.html

Answer (score 3):

In response to your specific questions:

- `input()` reads the next character from the input stream.
- `unput(ch)` puts the character `ch` back into the input stream.

These are effectively equivalent to the standard C library functions `getc(yyin)` and `ungetc(ch, yyin)`, except that `flex` internally buffers `yyin`, so you have to use flex's internal functions.

- `SUBSTR(ING)?/"("` is a (f)lex-style regular expression. The parentheses and question mark are normal regex operators, just like pretty well any other regex dialect, so up to that point it means "either the word `SUBSTR` or the word `SUBSTRING`". The <kbd>/</kbd> operator is flex-specific: it specifies trailing context, rather like a lookahead assertion in Perl regexes, except that in flex it cannot be used inside a regular expression. The quotes are also flex-specific: they surround literal text, so that `"("` means "a literal <kbd>(</kbd>". So the entire regular expression will match either the word `SUBSTR` or the word `SUBSTRING` if followed immediately by an open parenthesis.

If you want to learn flex and bison, John Levine's book is an excellent resource. However, you should probably start at the beginning and read it through until the end.